# GatsbyJS - Automatically re-build & deploy project on changes in the Wordpress backend?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api, gatsby

I was wondering whether there is a way to automatically re-build & deploy my gatsbys site, once something changes in the wordpress layer (i.e. somebody adds a post)?

I am thinking of using gatsbyjs with a client and want to enable the client to update content automatically, but would love to keep the site static. Is 
there anything like this out there? Any advice on how I may proceed?

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a webhook from WordPress that will trigger your Gatsby build process to run again. If you are deploying to Netlify, they support webhooks to trigger rebuilds. If you have some other build process, you will need to decide how to have it re-run on a web hook.

WordPress.com supports webhooks, and there are plugins available for self hosted WordPress sites.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for this answer. But how? How to trigger Gatsby from the CMS? it's `.sh`? Do you have an example please?

Comment: That depends on where your Gatsby site is being built. If you're using netlify, they have webhook support. If you're doing something custom on your own server, you'll need to figure out a way to have the build command run from a WordPress hook. Feel free to post a new question and mention me if you have a specific question on that process.